# Importar ficheiro CSV PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, csv

Tenho um ficheiro CSV com contatos. Quero importar esses contatos para uma base de dados sqlite. Como posso ler o ficheiro e inserir para a base de dados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php).

Segue um exemplo de uso, supondo uma tabela `CONTATO(Nome, Funcao, Morada)` e uma linha no CSV do tipo `costa;Programador;Lisboa;`:

```
<?php
if ($db = sqlite_open("c:/teste.db", 0666, $error)) {
   echo "Banco de dados aberto...";
} else {
   die ($error);
}

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("teste.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num campos na linha $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        $query = "INSERT INTO CONTATO (Nome, Funcao, Morada) VALUES(";
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            // Inserindo os dados no banco.
            $query .= "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data[$c]) . "'";
            if ($c+1 < $num) {
               $query .= ",";
            }
        }
        $query .= ")";
        sqlite_query($db, $query);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Tenho um problema ao inserir na tabela. Da erro SQLite3::exec(): near "affaires", isso sera devido e ter carateres especiais no ficheiro csv, como palavras "d'Affaires", d'exploitation?

Comment: Possivelmente. Tem como fazer um teste com palavras sem aspas?

Comment: Sim fiz um teste e o problema vem mesmo das aspas. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Você pode usar a função `mysql_real_escape_string()`, que trata as palavras com aspas. Editei a resposta para usar a função.

Comment: Continua a dar o mesmo erro. E como posso separar por diferentes colunas na tabela (Nome, contato, morada, etc), por exemplo para este contato no csv: exemplo;costa;Programador;00000000;;Lisboa;CP;Portugal;;;;

Comment: Cada índice da variável `$data` é um campo da linha no CSV. Editei a resposta com um exemplo.

Comment: Lembrando que o separador nos campos no meu exemplo está como `,`. Se no seu arquivo está como `;`, deves mudar na função `fgetcsv()`. Por exemplo: `fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")`

Comment: E para mudar de linha? no final de cada contato, os ultimos carateres são ;;;;

Comment: E caso um campo no ficheiro CSV, estiver vazio ou em falta da erro. Como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: Se você tem o número de campos definido pode trocar a variável `$num` pelo número de campos por linha. Daí ele ignora os últimos `;;;`. Quando o campo vazio, pode testar se a variável `$data[$c]` está vazia antes de inserir no banco.

Comment: Utilizei if($data[$c]==''){$query .= " ";} para caso não tiver nada, escrever em branco. Como posso trocar a variavel pelo num de campos?

Comment: Na linha onde tem `$num = count($data);` pode colocar `$num = 5;` caso sejam 5 campos.

Comment: Tenho 13 campos, alterei $num=13; e das varios erros, Undefined offset: 1,Undefined offset: 2, ...