# Acessando arquivo .csv com PHP

Tags: php, csv, txt

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar e armazenar dados de colunas em um arquivo .csv com PHP?

Comment: [Importar ficheiro CSV PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39882/91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para gravar em um arquivo creio que seja da seguinte forma

```
//você pode transformar os dados em uma array para cada coluna e linha
$dados = array(
        //array('ID','Nome','Endereço','Telefone'),
        array('1','Maria da Silva','Rua da Maria','(11)12345678'),
        array('2','Pedro Cardoso','Rua do Pedro','(11)12345678'),
        array('3','Joana Pereira','Rua da Joana','(11)12345678')
      );
            //aqui você grava os dados em um arquivo csv
            $file = new SplFileObject('dados.csv','w');
            $file->setCsvControl(',');

            foreach($dados as $linha){
                $file->fputcsv($linha);
            }
```

e pra pegar os dados eu busquei no manual do php

```
$file = new SplFileObject("dados.csv",'r');
//enquanto nao for o fim do arquivo
    while (!$file->eof()) {
    var_dump($file->fgetcsv());
}
```